# Is there an ideal way to catch exceptions when using the Async library in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

We use AWS Lambda for the backend of our mobile application. I just realized that our uncaught exceptions were not being logged correctly so we could be alerted to them. I realize that we could use something like this

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    console.log(...)
    process.exit(1) //mandatory (as per the Node docs)
})
```

This has a lot of problems though as I do not believe we could push the error into our SNS log stream. Ideally, we'd like to put a try catch block around some of our main processing code, but this does not work as its getting called asynchronously and it does not get caught

```
  async.waterfall([
            async.apply(verifyCacheIsReady, request_data),     
            async.apply(verifyRequestAndGetUser, request_data),               
            async.apply(logSession, request_data)],
            function (command_callback)
            {
            }, 
            function(err)
            {
            }
```

I realize I could try catch in all of this functions, but this is a simplified version. Is there a good way to catch something that happens in this block of code?

Comment: Consistent and clean exception handling is what promises are very good at.  You may want to switch to a promise-based design.